# One step ahead forecast with new data collected sequentially using dshw from forecast package

Tags: r, time-series

This is solved for Arima in the following [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55168/one-step-ahead-forecast-with-new-data-collected-sequentially)

Now I would like to compare dshw to Arima but I didn't find the feature of passing fitted model to dshw to avoid reestimating the model every time we update the data set with new values. The following doesn't work:

```
set.seed(1234)
y=ts(log(35+10*rnorm(1000)))
set.seed(4567)
new.data=ts(log(35+10*rnorm(10)))

library(forecast)
model <- dshw(y)
newfit <- dshw(c(y,new.data), model=model)
onestep.for <- fitted(newfit)[1001:1010]
```

An alternative is doing a loop but I would like to avoid reestimating coefficients for each loop:

```
set.seed(1234)
y=ts(log(35+10*rnorm(1000)))
set.seed(4567)
new.data=ts(log(35+10*rnorm(10)))

library(forecast)
model <- dshw(y)

onestep.for=forecast(model,h=1)
onestep.for=onestep.for$mean
for (i in 1:10) {
  data=c()
  data=c(y,new.data[1:i])
  model2= dshw(data)
  newfit=forecast(model2, h=1)
  onestep.for=c(onestep.for,newfit$mean)
}
```

Anyway I get the following error when running the code above

```
Error in min(y) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems with your code:

1. `dshw()` works on time series with multiple seasonal periods. You
   have a non-seasonal time series.
2. Unlike `Arima()`, `dshw()` returns forecasts. You don't need to call the `forecast`
   function to  obtain the forecasts.

You can do what you want by specifying the parameters in each subsequent call to `dshw()`:

```
# Fit the model to the training data assuming periods 3 and 12
fit <- dshw(y, period1=3, period2=12, h=1)
model <- fit$model

# Compute one-step forecasts for the test data without re-estimating parameters
onestep.for <- rep(NA, 10)
onestep.for <- fit$mean[1]
for(i in 1:9) {
   onestep.for[i+1] <- dshw(c(y,new.data[1:i]), period1=3, period2=12,
      h=1, alpha=model$alpha, beta=model$beta, gamma=model$gamma,
      omega=model$omega, phi=model$phi, lambda=model$lambda)$mean
}
```

I can make this easier by adding a `model` argument to `dshw()` as with `Arima()` and `ets()`. Something for the next version of the `forecast` package.